Casting the truth value of an inequality to a boolean
The problem I am trying to solve is very similar to this one or this other one, except that I would not necessarily want to limit it to integer variables (but it could be a start if nothing else is possible).
I have an expression $d = x_1 - x_2 - w_2$, where:
$0 \le x_1 \le W - w_1$
$0 \le x_2 \le W - w_2$
$W > 0$
$0 \le w_1 \le W$
$0 \le w_2 \le W$
I want to define a binary (boolean) variable $b$ such that:
$d \ge 0 \implies b = 1$
$d < 0 \implies b = 0$
It seemed to me that this solution or this other one should work, but then I am not sure how I would encode a constraint like $U b - d > 0$ in a linear program, given that I can only use $\le$ or $\ge$.
Should I use $\ge$ with a small $\epsilon$ added to the right hand side?
Then I am also struggling with the upper and lower bounds, but first I would like to understand if this approach is valid at all.
EDIT based on Rob Pratt's reply, trying* to write out a method by which I could have figured this out.
(trying* = as in: if I am writing any nonsense, please do let me know)
First for the case where $d$ is an integer, which implies that $d < 0$ can be replaced by $d \le -1$.
Suppose the two constraints I need are linear functions of $d$ and $b$.
$(1) Ad + Bb + C \ge 0$
$(2) A'd + B'b + C' \ge 0$
If I set $b = 0$ for the first constraint, I want it to reduce to $d \le -1$. Thus:
$(1) Ad + C \ge 0$
$d \le -1 \iff -d - 1 \ge 0$
$\implies A=C=-1$
If I set $b = 1$ for the second constraint, I want it to reduce to $d \ge 0$. Thus:
$(2) A'd + B' + C' \ge 0$
$d \ge 0$
$\implies A' = 1, B' + C' = 0$
So we now have:
$(1) -d + Bb -1 \ge 0$
$(2) d + B'b - B' \ge 0$
These two constraints need to remain true in the complementary cases of $b$, i.e. the first one when $b=1$:
$(1) -d + B -1 \ge 0$
$d \le B -1$
which is always true if $B-1$ is an upper bound $U$ for $d$, i.e. $B = U+1$.
And the second one when $b=0$:
$(2) d - B' \ge 0$
$d \ge B'$
which is always true if $B'$ is a lower bound $L$ for $d$.
Overall, after substitution and some rearrangement of signs:
$(1) d - (U+1)b +1 \le 0$
$(2) d - L(1- b) \ge 0$
Checking this in Excel seems to work:

Repeating the same procedure for the case where $d$ is continuous, the only change being that $d < 0$ is replaced by $d \le -\epsilon$, with $\epsilon$ being a very small real positive value.
The second constraint is not affected.
If I set $b = 0$ for the first constraint, I want it to reduce to $d \le -\epsilon$. Thus:
$(1) Ad + C \ge 0$
$d \le -\epsilon \iff -d - \epsilon \ge 0$
$\implies A=-1, C=-\epsilon$
So we now have:
$(1) -d + Bb -\epsilon \ge 0$
$(2) d + B'b - B' \ge 0$
These two constraints need to remain true in the complementary cases of $b$, i.e. the first one when $b=1$:
$(1) -d + B -\epsilon \ge 0$
$d \le B -\epsilon$
which is always true if $B-\epsilon$ is an upper bound $U$ for $d$, i.e. $B = U+\epsilon$.
Overall:
$(1) d - (U+\epsilon)b +\epsilon \le 0$
$(2) d - L(1- b) \ge 0$
which seems equivalent to Rob Pratt's answer, and also seems to work with some numerical values in Excel:

Perhaps one more thing that I need to figure out is why $L$ needs to be negative for the second constraint to work correctly.
Of course I understand that if $L$ is positive, the condition $d < 0$ can never be true; still, something does not convince me about it.

Equivalently, you want to enforce the contrapositives
\begin{align}
b=0 &\implies d<0 \\
b=1 &\implies d\ge 0
\end{align}
For $d<0$, rewrite as $d\le -\epsilon$ for some positive constant tolerance $\epsilon$.  If $d$ is an integer variable, you can take $\epsilon=1$.  Some solvers support such “indicator constraints” directly. Otherwise, you can use a big-M formulation as follows, where $\underline{d}$ and $\bar{d}$ are constant lower and upper bounds on $d$, respectively:
\begin{align}
d + \epsilon &\le (\bar{d} + \epsilon) b \tag1\label1\\
-d &\le (-\underline{d})(1-b) \tag2\label2
\end{align}

If $b=0$, then \eqref{1} enforces $d \le -\epsilon$ and \eqref{2} enforces the redundant $d \ge \underline{d}$.
If $b=1$, then \eqref{2} enforces $d \ge 0$ and \eqref{1} enforces the redundant $d \le \bar{d}$.


Thanks. I think the problem is that I am getting hints and finding bits and pieces a bit here and there, but no consistent, unified procedure or step by step method that describes how this is done. If there is any reference literature that describes how to do this, I would appreciate if someone could please point me to it. BTW I tried the big M method, but that specific post refers to integers, which as I said is not a limitation I would want to introduce. As for the other method, I may give it a shot, but it was again described for a problem with integer d, so not sure of its relevance.

H. Paul Williams, Model Building in Mathematical Programming (2013)

Excellent, thanks!

@user6376297 Also, there are many more such examples on (or.stackexchange.com) by simply searching for a keyword like linearization. :)

@A.Omidi : OK, can you please point me to one of them? Because I did search. Not on 'linearization' though, as I don't see what it has to do with the expression of the truth value of an inequality as a boolean. For me 'linearization' could be something like turning an absolute value objective to a linear one.

@user6376297, as a good starting point please, see this and this links.
